# What does the parameter ~sensor_model/max_range mean in octomap server?

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

With the sensor_model/max_range set to 5, the points of my point cloud that are longer than 5 still get inserted in the map. e.g. the max readings from the LRF

What does sensor_model/max_range really mean?
Do I have to filter the LRF max readings in individual scans before assembling it to the point cloud?

Thank you in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37040/what-does-the-parameter-%7Esensor_model/max_range-mean-in-octomap-server-?/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

octomap_server will truncate all rays longer than max_range to that range and clear up to that range. That means that longer rays won't be dropped but will still be used to update the free space. If your max range measurements actually mean errors which should not be integrated then you need to filter the points yourself or set them to "nan" in the point cloud. These error values will then be dropped.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-22**:
@AHornung does this mean an error? [http://imgur.com/5MFk1](https://imgur.com/5MFk1) Here the sphere is 30m max readings. I think I should filter the max LRF readings, then. My launch file has

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-06-22**:
The link with the image is not loading. But the parameter needs to be "" in the octomap_server's private node namespace.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-22**:
@AHornung Ok thanks. now it works

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reading beyond defined max_range be capped to this max_range. Octomap_server will do this task.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-21**:
@prince you mean those readings will not be inserted to the map right? but in rviz my map (marker array) displays max LRF readings inserted in the map by the octomap. why is that?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-06-21**:
Any laser array reading is considered only upto max_range for clearing obstacle. It is still used completely for mapping. Are obstacles not getting cleaned properly in such laser readings?

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-22**:
@prince Thanks